# How to extract Arrays from List in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List of arrays like this

```
private List<Array> _data = new List<Array>();
```

I want to add single array as single element of list Like this..

```
while(someCondition)
{
    string[] BioData = new string[3];
    BioData[0] = name;
    BioData[1] = age;
    BioData[2] = location;
    _data.Add(BioData);
}
```

The problem is how to retrieve arrays from that list..
Here is pseudo code what I want to do..

```
private void LoadData()
{
    string[] data= new string[3]; 
    foreach(var data[] in _data)
    {
        name= data[0];
        age= data[1];
        location= data[2];
    }
}
```

But it's not working. Kindly guide me how to achieve it. Thank You

Comment: It's a list of `Array`s, so you retrieve an `Array`. If you meant to create a `List<string[]>`, you should have done so.

Comment: I think the line _foreach(var data[] in -data)_ has errors. _foreach(var data in __data)_ would be better. The line above seems completely obsolete. with visual Studio or VisualStudio Code you'd see many red squiggly lines that would indicate the syntactic errors. Also the comment of @GSerg is correct.

Comment: Never use stringly typing.  Declare a class that has a Name, Age and Location property.  The rest takes care of itself.

Comment: DanielSchmid yes the error was in foreach(var data[] in _data)... I have corrected it..
GSerg yes I have made changes and it's working..
Thank you

Comment: Consider this way: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RT2CFE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want the `Array` class, just use `string[]` instead.

So it would be like:

```
private List<string[]> _data = new List<string[]>();

...

foreach (var data in _data)
{
    name = data[0];
    age = data[1];
    location = data[2];
}
```

You can test it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F8ouIe). Please note the output and some code changes.